# ESXI 4.0 Slow response in opening anything accross the network on a Virtual Server running Win2008

Tags: windows, vmware-esxi

Hi I recently installed a HP ML350G6 Server with Windows Small Business Server 200864bit, Exchange 2007. The server was running fantastically and we transferred all user data onto the new server and no problems for 2 weeks!
We then installed SQL2008 and transferred the accounts package onto the server and this is where the problems started. Users are now complaining to open a work document can take 2 minutes and the same with regard to anything else.
The server itself seems fine, the virtual server seems fine! No disk performance problems (doesn't go above 50% unless i really copy lots of things), no memory, (12Gb only using 7Gb) cpu (usage is low average about 15%) etc on both the VM and in Windows Task manager. I have made sure disk caching is enabled on the raid controller (which made no difference). Network cards are running 1Gb and plugged into HP GB switch. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Just found an article on the web with the answer http://www.petri.co.il/how-to-disable-smb-2-on-windows-vista-or-server-2008.htm

Thank goodness for Google!!!

Answer (score 0):

Is this machine your active directory controller? Does everything show up right in DNS?